# How do I properly convert a h5 file to pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I trained a model using https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/ and it gave me a `keras_model.h5` file and a `labels.txt` and I want to use it with OpenCV for some object detection but I've only used OpenCV with `.pb` files. So I'm thinking that I would have to convert it somehow. So I started looking around and I found this. https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow and when I try to run the script in my conda environment it throws this exception.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From keras_to_tensorflow.py:23: set_learning_phase (from tensorflow.python.keras.backend) is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11.
Instructions for updating:
Simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
2021-01-23 05:58:15.012748: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
I0123 05:58:16.157379  5660 keras_to_tensorflow.py:145] Converted output node names are: ['sequential_3/dense_Dense2/Softmax']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_to_tensorflow.py", line 182, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\developer\miniconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\developer\miniconda3\envs\tf1\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "keras_to_tensorflow.py", line 148, in main
    sess = K.get_session()
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'get_session'
```

Why is that and how do I properly convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load the keras .h5 model and save loaded model as .pb

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model(keras_model_path_location)
model.save(model, "save/path/to/location")
```